# How to remove unused space in ngx-charts?

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I have a table where some of the cells contain an ngx-chart: [image: ngx-charts]

As you can see on the picture, there is some space between the line and the cell border on each side. Is it possible to remove this space so the cell's size gets reduced?

HTML:

```
<td>
  <ngx-charts-line-chart [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="patient.vitalSigns[0]" [gradient]="gradient"
  [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [autoScale]="autoScale">
  </ngx-charts-line-chart>
</td>
```

.ts:

```
view: any[] = [150, 35];

colorScheme = {
  domain: ['#3f51b5'] 
}

gradient = false;

showXAxis = false;
showYAxis = false;
showLegend = false;

showXAxisLabel = false;
xAxisLabel = 'Time';
showYAxisLabel = false;
yAxisLabel = 'Value';

autoScale = true;
```